# How to conditionally reformat user input if a date string of dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd?

Tags: php, date, user-input, date-formatting

I've added Search functionality in my form. When a user enters date `18/03/2015` then I want to reformat the date.  I need to change `$_GET['searchKeyword']` from `'18/03/2015'` to `'2015-03-18'` and save as `$searchKeyword`.

I want this for my sql `LIKE` clause.
I write like this, but it is not working:

```
$where_clause = ''; 
$searchKeyword =  $_GET['search_keyword'];

if ($_GET['search_keyword'] != '')
{   
    if (preg_match('/^(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d\d\d\d)$/', $_GET['searchKeyword'], $m)) 
    {
        $searchKeyword = "$m[3]-$m[2]-$m[1]";
        $where_clause = " where patient_id  like '%" .$searchKeyword . "%'
                          or patient_name like '%" .$searchKeyword . "%'
                          or in_date like '%" . $searchKeyword . "%'
                          or discharge_date like '%" . $searchKeyword ."%'";    
    } else {
        $where_clause = " where patient_id  like '%" .$searchKeyword . "%'
                          or patient_name like '%" .$searchKeyword . "%'
                          or in_date like '%" . $searchKeyword . "%'
                          or discharge_date like '%" . $searchKeyword . "%'";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your concern to make `'18/03/2015'` look like `'2015-03-18'` or to form your SQL query?

Comment: please see my newly edited question

Comment: I assume the `f` instead of `if` is just a typo (solution: copy/paste). But now you've got something but it's "not working" - not working in what sense? Have you `echo`ed your `$searchKeyword` or your `$where_clause` to see what value it contains?

Comment: Some minor thoughts - use your `if` to set the `$searchKeyword` but then stay DRY and set your `$where_clause` outside the if since it seems identical. Also be aware that within double-quotes variables will be substituted and so you don't have to keep closing them, concatenating, and re-opening them.  `"yada yada LIKE '%$searchKeyword%' yada-yada"` works just fine.

Comment: Also be aware that you are breaking a cardinal rule and will soon have the SQL-Injection Police coming down on you. NEVER use user-supplied data in a query unless you have THOROUGHLY sanitized it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break it down into 2 parts:

(1) Find out if it matches the pattern

```
if (preg_match('/^(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d\d\d\d)$/', $_GET['searchKeyword'], $m)) {
```

(2) Assign to your variable

```
    $searchKeyword = "$m[3]-$m[2]-$m[1]";
}
```

The regex above "captured" 3 different groups (the part in parens) which are then available as `$m[1]`, `$m[2]`, and `$m[3]`, respectively. You can swap them around and format them as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `date` function of php as

```
$get_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_GET['searchKeyword']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [PHP Date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_GET['searchKeyword']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is currently insecure (vulnerable to injection attacks) because you are using unfiltered user-supplied data in your query.  Using mysqli's prepared statements with placeholders will tidy up this issue nicely.

I am going to assume that your `patient_id` column is an `INT` type (but I don't know your table structure).  If it is not, you can undo my `CAST()`.

As for using `LIKE` on `DATE` type data (I don't know your table structure), please read [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/96249).  This is a reasonable argument for re-engineering the query-build using `YEAR`/`MONTH`/`DAY`.

I've taken the liberty of making your search functionality "more inclusive".  Not only does my query search your four desired columns using `LIKE`, when the submitted string *can* be interpreted as a date (by `strtotime()`), two more conditions are added to the `WHERE` clause that use the formatted data on the two date columns.

Effectively, if a user types: `yesterday`, then any rows with a patient name containing `yesterday` or with an `in_date` exactly matching `2018-04-21` or `discharge_date` exactly matching `2018-04-21` will be returned.  (at time of posting, it is April 22, 2018)  Likewise, an input of `March 31` will search the date columns for matches of `2018-03-31`.  Nothing lost; only more security and flexibility, but perhaps maybe too many rows returned (that is for you to determine).

```
if (!$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database")) {  // use your own details obviously
    echo "Connect failed: " , $conn->connect_error);  // never display errors to the public
} elseif (empty($_GET['search_keyword'])) {
    if (!$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `table`")) {
        echo "Syntax error on query with no keyword";
    } else {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            // do what you wish with $row['columnname']
        }
    }
} else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE";
    $query .= " CAST(`patient_id` AS CHAR) LIKE ? OR `patient_name` LIKE ?";
    $query .= " OR `in_date` LIKE ? OR `discharge_date` LIKE ?";
    $wrapped = "%" . $_GET['search_keyword'] . "%";  // wrap the values with % for binding downscript
    if (($unix = strtotime($_GET['search_keyword'])) !== false) {
        $query .= " OR `in_date` = ? OR `discharge_date` = ?";
        $reformatted = date('Y-m-d', $unix);
    }
    if(!$stmt=$conn->prepare($query)) {
        echo "Error on prepare: " , $conn->error;
    } elseif (isset($reformatted) && !$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $wrapped,  $wrapped, $wrapped, $wrapped, $reformatted, $reformatted)) {
        echo "Error on bind (x6 params): " , $stmt->error;
    } elseif (!isset($reformatted) && !$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $wrapped, $wrapped, $wrapped, $wrapped)) {
        echo "Error on bind (x4 params): " , $stmt->error;
    } elseif (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Error on execute: " , $stmt->error;
    } elseif (!$result = $stmt->get_result()) {
        echo "Error on get result: " , $stmt->error;
    } else {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            // do what you wish with $row['columnname']
        }
    }
}
```